# Electron splashscreen on startup application

Tags: node.js, electron

I've been using Django a lot and now I'm playing with Electron as I would like to create a desktop app.

I wonder is there an easy way to create a splash screen (frameless window) only to display a logo for a few seconds then open a "normal" window where the main application will be rendered ?

Thanks,

Arnaud

Comment: I think this can be helpfull https://discuss.atom.io/t/help-creating-a-splash-screen-on-electron/19089

Comment: Electron is just a wrapper for web application. Show a dialog when page is loaded and use a setTimeout to hide it. You can use any javascript frameworks to do this.

Comment: Hi all. Showing and hiding the window is the first idea I had. But how can I display a frameless window then a normal window ?

Answer (score 30):

A simple splash screen for electron could be something like

```
let splash

app.on('ready', () => {
  // create main browser window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      show: false // don't show the main window
  });
  // create a new `splash`-Window 
  splash = new BrowserWindow({width: 810, height: 610, transparent: true, frame: false, alwaysOnTop: true});
  splash.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // if main window is ready to show, then destroy the splash window and show up the main window
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    splash.destroy();
    mainWindow.show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be appropriate to disclose the source of this, if it is indeed amlang's comment from that [linked atom.io discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/help-creating-a-splash-screen-on-electron/19089/8) ?

Comment: Instead of using ready-to-show, you can use did-finish-load to ensure that the page has finished loading completely. 'mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () ...'

Answer (score 16):

To get a frameless window, just set the `frameless` option to `true` when creating a new `BrowserWindow` — known as the [Frameless API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md):

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600, 
    frame: false
});
win.show();
```

Just show that window before you show your 'main' application window, when the app fires the `ready` event.